# Why are there no control structures for python FOR loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

In Java, we can have a FOR loop like this

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {

}
```

Yet this is not possible in Python; FOR can only be used in the "foreach" sense, looping through each element in an iterable.

Why were the control structures for the FOR loop left out in Python?

Comment: You can accomplish the same with something like `xrange`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says “There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.”  Python already has this way to do it:

```
for i in xrange(10):
    pass
```

If you want to make all the parts explicit, you can do that too:

```
for i in xrange(0, 10, 1):
    pass
```

Since it already has an “obvious” way to do it, adding another way would be un-zen.  (Would that be “nez”?)

(Note: In Python 3, use `range` instead of `xrange`.)

A C-style `for` loop has more flexibility, but ultimately you can write an equivalent loop with Python's `while` (or C's `while` for that matter), which touches not only on the “one obvious way” principle, but also “Simple is better than complex” amongst others.  This is all a matter of taste, of course—in this case, Guido van Rossum's taste.

Comment: and `cython` is smart enough to special case these loops into c-style for loops without the overhead of `xrange`. I wouldn't be surprised if `pypy` recognises it too.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is one of those questions that goes back to the mists of Python 0.x (in fact, most likely to its predecessor ABC), the only person who can really answer is Guido, and then only if he remembers. You could try asking him to write a post on his [History of Python](http://python-history.blogspot.com) blog.

However, there are some good reasons for this.

First, having only a single form of `for` instead of two different forms makes the language smaller—simpler to learn and read for humans, and simpler to parse for computers.

Not having the "foreach"-style `for` loop leads to many off-by-one errors, and makes a lot of simple code much more verbose.

Not having the C-style `for` loop makes some already-very-complicated `for` loops slightly more complicated by forcing them to be `while` loops. It doesn't affect simple loops like yours, which can be written as "foreach" loops, like `for i in range(10):`—which is briefer, and more readable, and harder to get wrong.*

When looked at that way, the choice is obvious.

---

* In fact, even *complex* loops can be turned into foreach loops, via iterators. And sometimes that's a good idea. For example, is `for (int i=2; i=next_prime(i); i<1000000)` really better than `for i in takewhile(lambda i: i<1000000, generate_primes()):`? There's a reason that C++ has gradually added features to make the latter possible, to avoid the mistakes you can easily make with the former…

Answer (score 1):

Generally, It is better performance to iterate over the elements. You can have the same result with:

```
for i in xrange(0, 20):
    pass
```

And you should defenetly read the zed of python:
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

Answer (score 0):

Because it's just syntactic sugar for a while loop

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    # stuff
    i += 1
```

Put up your hand if you've never had an off-by-one error in a C-style-for loop. Thought so.

Comment: Well, a foreach loop is _also_ just syntactic sugar for [a while loop](http://pastebin.com/S9AqxGMJ), but it's still worth having…

Comment: A C-style for loop is *not* syntactic sugar for that particular `while` loop, though, because if you `continue` in a C-style for loop then the continuation code `i += 1` is executed. Not so in that `while` loop. In this case the "obvious" fix is to put `i += 1` at the start of the loop, change `i = 0` to `i = -1` and change `i < 10` to `i < 9`, but it's possible to get into a bit of a mess trying to write a full equivalent of C-style for :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop, you're right. My answer is oversimplified. You also can't easily handle loops doing assignments in the while expression. I'll put it down to my habit of attempting to program defensively and avoiding twisty C loops where possible.

Comment: If I need to do anything too fancy to translate into an obvious `for`, `while`, or `while True: … break …`, I put the fancy bit in a genexpr (or `itertools` call or …) and then it becomes an obvious `for` loop, where `break` and `continue` mean exactly what you want them to…

Comment: @abarnert, and it's good practice, because you can unittest your generator if it's complex.

Comment: @gnibbler: Yeah, and you can debug-via-print by doing `my_generator = list(my_generator); print(my_generator, file=stderr)`. Of course every so often you do that having forgotten how big your iterator can be and flood the console or even thrash swap and bring your computer to a grinding halt… but it's nice to be able to do it when you're _not_ that stupid. :)